# conversion of ActionScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

It is mentioned that the Flash CC supports ActionScript 3.0 . When we try to convert a swf file which was generated using ActionScript 3.0 into HTML5, it is commenting out all the ActionScript code. So that we need to write JavaScript instead of Action Script. Is it happening to support HTML5? OR anything else? I am just curious to know the reason. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some code... Or give an more specific example. We have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @Johnston actually i am not talking about any specific code. I am just mentioning the functionality . Earlier I have worked with Flash CS 5.5 and generated some scenes. Now i want to convert those scenes into html5 in Flash CC sothat I can run my project in browser too. Whenever I click the convert option in command panel, it is commenting out all the action script code and failed to give browser support.

Comment: The solution for this is to replace the ActionScript code with JavaScript. So I am just wondering why this is all happening .

Comment: There's no magic behind that conversion, the AS3 code is stripped out cos it doesn't convert to Javascript, why would it? If you want a html scene made in Flash CC then write the javascript yourself. If you hope for a magic tool to convert AS3 to javascript, stop dreaming.

Comment: I know that there is no such tool available. But i have posted this to know the reason behind.

Comment: The reason is that even so JavaScript and ActionScripts are both ECMAScript languages, they are different languages. And second: code you need to work with Flash scene object is different from the code you will need to work with HTML DOM

Comment: Conversion of AS3 to JS is conceivable (see [Jangaroo](http://www.jangaroo.net/), [FlexJS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/FlexJS)) but Adobe simply hasn't done this with Flash Pro CC.